# Is flagging as "asking for code translation" allowed?

Tags: discussion, support

So, I was recently banned from flagging because three flags from the past 7 days of mine were rejected.  When I went to view them I was surprised about 2 of them being rejected, but I only want to ask about one.  **If a moderator would like to PM me about the other, I would be happy to speak with them.**

---

I flagged a post for moderator review because it was "asking for a code translation service," which I believe is supposed to be flagged in that category (from other meta threads).  It was rejected on the grounds

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

**not on the grounds that there wasn't evidence.**  (see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbu1w.jpg) for the flag).
This was interesting to me because just a week before, I had a mod flag accepted on these grounds.  See the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4pXo.jpg).  **So moderators, do you not want flags about asking for a code translation service?**

> I just want this to be consistent because if I flag a post for an obvious reason and it is helpful, I will continue to do so in the future.  **I would not have flagged this as "asking for a code translation" if my previous one wasn't accepted.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your flag was declined because you didn't need to use a custom moderator flag for this. Simply use an appropriate close vote flag, and the community will review the question for closure.

Custom moderator flags are for items that the community cannot handle itself. Moderators are intended to be exception handlers.

As for why your other flag was accepted, well, the question had already been closed and deleted by the time I got to it so it was easier to mark that flag as helpful than decline it. To be consistent, I probably should have declined that flag as well.

In the future, I recommend using one of the standard close vote reasons or close flags rather than a custom flag for questions like this.

Comment: Could you PM me about the other flag please?  Also, do you feel it would be fair to ban someone from flagging because of an error?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a private message facility on the site, aside from moderator warnings and suspensions. I wasn't the one who handled the other flag, so I'm not sure I'd be able to explain the thought process there.

Comment: Is there anyway I can challenge the ban?  I feel it was completely wrong.  If needed, I can make a whole new meta thread, but I don't feel it is necessary.